# localhost view from other local computers

Tags: wordpress, web, localhost, local

I created a website using wordpress in my localhost (A) computer but when I'm trying to see it from (B) computer, I cant see it normally with themes and some stuffs are missing, it has most text content.

i'm also using in the url = localhost/wordpress maybe there is the problem , but how can i fix this ? 
sorry for my bad English

Comment: You have to enter the real url of the site. Localhost actually means localhost

Comment: how can i do that with my Wordpress already created.

Comment: Ask google, there are tonns of answers for this

Comment: is any way i can do that ?? without deleting my existing wordpress or without changing anything on it ?

Comment: You will have to  change it on the wordpress side, no way arround this

Comment: i searched already , thats why i'm here to get any good answer

Comment: can i change it on php admin?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed wamp. Make the wamp server online and setup the wordpress site using the IP address of a computer. For example http://192.168.1.9/wordpress. Then you can browse the site anywhere from LAN.